# How to select rows containing ONLY cyrillic characters in UPPERCASE from the table using LIKE statement in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select rows where column `[Name]` contains ONLY Cyrillic characters in UPPERCASE, and comma and hyphen from the table using `LIKE` :

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Clients
WHERE   NAME    LIKE '%[А-Я][,-]%' COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CS_AS
```

Or using explicit pattern:

```
SELECT *
FROM Clients
WHERE NAME LIKE '%[АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ][,-]%' COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CS_AS
```

But these selects rows in which at least one character exists in pattern (but allows any other characters not exists in pattern).

Maybe using `^` (NOT predicate) excluding any other characters like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Clients
WHERE   NAME    LIKE '%[^A-Z][./=+]%' COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CS_AS
```

But this requires enumeration a large number of unnecessary characters.

How best to make a selection?

Comment: Maybe you should create function to check for illegal characters and then use that function in `where` condition?

Answer (score 0):

Use a double negative. Search for rows where the column *doesn't* contain at least one character *not* in the set you're interested in:

```
SELECT *
FROM Clients
WHERE NAME NOT LIKE '%[^-АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ,]%' COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CS_AS
```

(I'm not quite sure what you were attempting to do by placing the hyphen and comma in a separate grouping, but I've moved them into the same group for now, since that seems to make some sense)

Comment: Thanks, Damien_The_Unbeliever !